# Meteor: loginWithGoogle without updating permission scope of user

Tags: javascript, meteor, calendar, google-calendar-api, meteor-accounts

My Meteor application lets user register and login with Google and by email/password.

When logging in with Google, I am only requesting for `email` permission. After logging in, the user can go to user settings and `Connect Google Calendar`, which will add the calendar permission to the user's scope (By executing another `loginWithGoogle` requesting calendar permission this time).

The problem is, every time a user logs in with Google account from the login page, the `scope` object is updated by `loginWithGoogle` function and the calendar scope is removed (because here the login function only requests for email permission).

Is there any way of logging in the user without updating/replacing the scope? I can not ask for calendar permission from Log In page because I want the users to be able to decide weather or not they want to sync their calendar with the app.

Thanks.

Comment: AFAIK, if you don't plan on setting the scope in the initial login, you have to put it as an [additional scopes](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/incremental-auth). In this way, you will not violate any privacy of the user (since you'll be asking for their permission (e.g. access/sync their calendar data)). This handshake of permission/s may depend on your implementation. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone else is looking for the answer, the solution was as easy was adding an option `include_granted_scopes:true` to the login options.

i.e.

```
Meteor.loginWithGoogle({
  requestPermission: ['email'],
  loginUrlParameters: {include_granted_scopes: true}
}, function(err){})
```